# Is there a Keyboard Shortcut to HIDE properties pane?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a Keyboard Shortcut to HIDE properties pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered an issue where VS2008 wouldn't display anything in the Properties window in the WPF designer if it was set to autohide. In my searching for a solution, I found this question. As noted in the question, <kbd>F4</kbd> normally only shows/focuses the Properties window. I followed the steps in Marcel's answer and modified the resulting macro as shown below to allow <kbd>F4</kbd> to instead toggle the Properties window:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module RecordingModule
    Sub TogglePropertiesTab()
        If DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindProperties).Visible Then
            DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindProperties).Close()
        Else
            DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindProperties).Activate()
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 4):

Detailed instructions for how to build a macro:

1. Bring up the Properties window
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to start Macro recording
3. Close the Properties Window
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to stop recording.
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to open the Macro Browser.
6. `RecordingModule > TemporaryMacro` contains your macro. Rename "RecordingModule" to something different. Should look like this:

---

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module RecordingModule
    Sub TemporaryMacro()
        DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindProperties).Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

---

1. `Tools > Customize` and there `Keyboard`
2. Search for (depending on how you renamed it) `Macros.MyMacros.RecordingModule1.TemporaryMacro` and choose your shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

If there's not you could always create a macro to close the properties window and bind the macro to a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

No, I've never seen anything to actually hide the properties pane.  Best you can do is set it to Auto Hide (click the Pin icon) and then use <kbd>F4</kbd> to open it up when you want it.  Then it will Auto Hide when you're done.

EDIT: Looks like you can create a macro for it as noted by the other Answers.  Nice!